# Using pandas to join on multiple soft keys and multiple hard keys with different names

Tags: pandas

Is it possible to use pandas to join on multiple soft keys e.g when we allow tolerance range for a match and multiple hard keys that are named differently in both tables?

It seems that `pandas.merge_asof` allows only to join on one soft key and does not allow to specify hard key names separately for left and right tables (in case they are differently named and renaming isn't easy to process).

Consider the following two datasets

table1:

soft keys: sk1, sk2

hard keys: x, y

```
sk1,sk2,x,y,val1
10,100,10,15,1
20,200,20,25,2
30,300,10,10,3
```

table2:

soft keys: sk1,sk2

hard keys: k1,k2

```
sk1,sk2,k1,k2,val2,x,y
15,110,10,15,3,1,1
23,230,20,25,5,2,2
34,330,10,10,-1,3,3
```

I would need something equivalent to

```
soft_merge(t1, t2, left_by=["x","y"], right_by=["k1","k2"], on=[sk1, sk2], tolerance=[5,15])
```

to get output (showed vals only for clarity):

```
val1 | val2
1    | 3
```

I understand that instead of `left_by` and `right_by` for hard keys we can just
use by and rename columns, but this might not be easily supportable by a system since other system components might rely on old namings. Is there any clean and nice way of achieving it without multiple naming-renaming?
But the problem of joining on multiple soft keys still remain unclear ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the tolerances after an exact merge:

```
m = df1.merge(df2, left_on=["x","y"], right_on=["k1","k2"])
mask = (m.sk1_x - m.sk1_y).abs().le(5) & (m.sk2_x - m.sk2_y).abs().le(15)

m.loc[mask, ['val1', 'val2']]
#   val1  val2
#0     1     3
```

---

This doesn't ensure a 1:1 merge, and will give all combinations that achieve that tolerance. If you need the "nearest" match you will need to specify some distance formula and keep only the closest. Here I use the total absolute distance. Assuming `val1` is a unique key:

```
m['dist'] = (m.sk1_x - m.sk1_y).abs() + (m.sk2_x - m.sk2_y).abs()
m.sort_values('dist').loc[mask].drop_duplicates('val1')
```